# How to Stream / Control Audio using Multitasking bar iOS 4+

Tags: ios4, avfoundation, mpmovieplayer, avplayer

im trying to find resources about the possibility to control audio stream from the multitasking bar in iOS 4+. So possibly when app reaches background, when the home button was pressed twice, the audio controls in the multitasking bar should give me some possibility to control my audio stream. I don't know if using simple mpmovieplayer is enough or i should go with AVFoundation.

This is a picture of what i'm meaning:

http://bayimg.com/AabFEAAdg

Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable iPod controls in the background to control non-iPod music in iOS 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196330/how-to-enable-ipod-controls-in-the-background-to-control-non-ipod-music-in-ios-4)

Comment: Started to answer your regex question and it got deleted. You must escape forward slashes if you're delimiting your regex pattern with forward slashes. `/\/([^\/]*\/?$/` That will match //, /foo, /foo/, but not /foo/bar