# how an app take over ipod app in an iPhone like this one?

Tags: iphone, ipod

When this app (douban.fm) is running, the default volume bar could control it playing/next instead of the iPod app. and there's a play icon in the status bar. and I believe the headset control could control the app as well.

I'm developing a similar music app and wondering how to accomplish this functionality that when my  app is running, users could use the control bar or headset control to play/next?

the play icon in status bar (near the battery icon)
https://picasaweb.google.com/nicoster/201134?feat=directlink#5580079059148648786

system music control now controls douban.fm
https://picasaweb.google.com/nicoster/201134?feat=directlink#5580079159380140162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this question. I think it'll help :)

[How to enable iPod controls in the background to control non-iPod music in iOS 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196330/iphone-how-to-enable-ipod-controls-in-the-background-to-control-non-ipod-music)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that post. I just didn't how to find it:)