# AVAudioPlayer play error and the error is Code=-54 "The operation couldn’t be completed when screen lock

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I user AVAudioPlayer playing music ,but when the screen lock .some phone will stop and the error is "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -54.)"";but some will normal play,who can tell me why......

Comment: I think that this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085049/avaudioplayer-stops-playing-on-screen-lock-even-though-the-category-is-avaudiose

Comment: Thank you very much.Why lock screen time, does not have permission to read some music files.
But there are some music files can be read.

Comment: Check my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59703250/4067700