# AVAudioPlayer can't open an audio while screen off. Error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I try to play the next audio when the current audio is finished I catch `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying`.
It works ok when the iPhone screen on.
If I turn off the screen I get the error `Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54` when I try to open the next audio by `AVAudioPlayer`.

```swift
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot initiate play while in the background, including locked screen. You can only continue what was already playing (if you are configured for background play).

Comment: I see a solution to make array of AVAudioPlayer while the screen on and switch between them. Is good?

Comment: @matt I checked it. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `AVAudioPlayer` as it supports playback rate but it doesn't support creating the instance of AVAudioPlayer in sleep device mode. 
My solution is to create arrays of AVAudioPlayer before the device will be slept.
When the current audio is finished you should to get the next instance from stored array.

You can check it [here](https://github.com/filimo/ReaderTranslator/blob/master/ReaderTranslatorPlayer/Store/AudioStore.swift)

```swift
let players = [AVAudioPlayer]()
let index = 0

do {
    player = [
        try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url1),
        try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url2),
        try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url3)
    ]
} catch {
    print(error)
}

players[index].play()

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        index += 1
        players[index].play()
    }
}
```