# How do I make my app work with the media control buttons on lock screen?

Tags: ios, media-player, mpmusicplayercontroller

In recent iOS versions apps have some kind of access to the media control buttons on the lock screen, like the Play/Pause button:

[image]

It looks like the buttons are supposed to work with the `MPMusicPlayerController` class, is that right? Is there a way to get the “raw” events from the buttons? Because the music player only seems to offer an API to supply a bunch of `MPMediaItem`s. What if my app is for example a radio that needs to handle the buttons differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit more searching I have found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196330) that makes things clear. The music player controller class is not really the right track, the trick is to subscribe for remote events in your controller:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{
    // see [event subtype] for details
}
```